# How to show everything on a page with scrollbar in dev tools?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I'm trying to make a whatsapp web bot that automatically kick user that send links in a group but if the group has a lot of members and the user is down there it does not identify the div element that would use to kick the user so I would have to scroll first, there is way to edit the css of the page so that it shows everything at once ?

Comment: Why you look for that user manually, do you do scroll down ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, body{ zoom: inherit;} or body{ zoom: 0.1;}